# Configure Cardboard view

Tags: android, google-vr

I´m developing a cardboard app and I´m interested in remove the vertical line which appears in the middle of the screen and divides both images, but i don´t know how to do this. Also I would like to remove the arrow which appears in the top left corner. In this image appears the elements I was talking about:

[image: VR Image]

Please, can anyone help me ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have both options in the game object with the Gvr Viewer script attached.

- The vertical line is the Alignment Market.
- The back button is the Back Button option.

[image: screenshot1]

Comment: Thanks!, but I´m using the VR SDK for android, not Unity :(